# it is Impossible for me to install ubuntu or generally most linux distros on Asus zenbook14 um433iq

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader, asus

I've got a big problem, I can't install ubuntu and some Ubuntu-based Linux distro but Pop Os on my laptop.
Let me illustrate the problem, I've tried elementary os, ubuntu, Feren os, KDE neon, Zorin os,... and after they get installed and I restart to enter os environment, they don't boot to Os environment.
I have not this problem with Pop os.
I recently bought the laptop and I am so disappointed about that, I will be so happy if you help to fix the problem. (I don't use dual-boot by the way)
Ubuntu version is 20.04.2 and others are based on the LTS version (Desktop version)
The current Linux distro on my machine is pop os 20.04.2 which works perfectly nice
if you wanna take a look at my laptop specs : [My Laptop Specs](https://laptopmedia.com/gb/review/asus-zenbook-14-um433-review-amd-and-nvidia-trying-to-conquer-the-ultrabook-world-together/)

Comment: Please ask here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  I will ask it there , thank you